# How to Parse HTML in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have used requests in python to get a temporary email box. I need to parse the mail id from the below HTML code(it's beside the "result:"). I have tried using the [parse](https://pypi.org/project/parse/) module of python but it is not giving the valid result, instead, I get None as a result.
Is there a way to parse from HTML using the left and the right matching strings?

Here is my code>

```
r = s.get('https://www.cs.email/inbox',verify = False)
html = r.text
par = parse('\"result: {\"list\":[{\"mail_id":"{}\",\"mail_from\":\"support@windscribe.com\"', html)
print(par)
```

HTML Below

```
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    gm_init_vars = {
        uid: '',
        usr: '',
        api_token : '6ef0a153476ab4ae2090f02d08f31a3a60dd6a70493cc43b397642e4d4f3a5e5',
        ryo_url: 'https://grr.la/ryo/cs.email/',
        hasFlash: false,
        ZeroSwf: '/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf',             passwordJs: '/js/password.min.js',
        ryoJs: '/js/ryo.js',
        bitcoinJs: '/js/bitcoin.js',
        recaptchaJs: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js',
        recaptcha2Js: '//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js',
        base: '/',
        tab: 'inbox',
        assets: '/',
        lang: 'en',
        ajax_url: 'www.cs.email/ajax.php',
        result: {"list":[{"mail_id":"507627420","mail_from":"support@windscribe.com","mail_subject":"Welcome to Windscribe, confirm your email address","mail_excerpt":"\n\t\n\t\t","mail_timestamp":"1587097890","mail_read":"0","mail_date":"04:31:30","att":"0","mail_size":"7429"}],"count":"1","email":"AvnaZrLDcuvwB@guerrillamailblock.com","alias":"kslqme+f9rnfatt6orhcs06gvgo0","ts":1587097897,"sid_token":"aruhantm0ogdh8hl55n1redm6h","stats":{"sequence_mail":"61,458,632","created_addresses":38163242,"received_emails":"12,682,145,335","total":"12,620,686,703","total_per_hour":"107550"},"auth":{"success":true,"error_codes":[]}},
        email_addr: 'AvnaZrLDcuvwB@guerrillamailblock.com',
        alias: 'kslqme+f9rnfatt6orhcs06gvgo0',
        use_alias: true,
        email_timestamp: 1587097897,
        domain: 'cs.email',
        site: 'elfyy',
        limit: 20,
        display_host: 'cs.email',
```

Comment: Regular expressions may be better. `re.search('"mail_id":"(\d+)"', html)` worked for me. You could expand that to include more of the string in front but that could be risky too. Who knows what subtle differences there could be message by message.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! , It worked for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the `parse` module but I don't see how it can beat regular expressions. You could use an HTML parser to find the script tag, but really just a regex search against the entire html text seems reasonable in this case.

Your data is embedded in a larger list but I recommend keeping the regex search narrow. You have to balance a false positive `"mail_id":"507627420"` match against the much more likely differences in the list from message to message. So,

```
import re
r = s.get('https://www.cs.email/inbox',verify = False)
match = re.search('"mail_id":"(\d+)"', r.text)
if match:
    mail_id = match.group(1)
    print(mail_id)
```

Comment: Can you help me with another regex of an alpha numeric and including special character string?. Like this :- aluhe3jm/609a4a6ff32f19a0e301085edda91d8c?ts=1587097870

Comment: @JovMan, in that example, the only special character as far as regex is concerned is `?`. A regex that matches that exact string is `r":- aluhe3jm/609a4a6ff32f19a0e301085edda91d8c\?ts=1587097870"`. If you wanted to pull out the stuff after the equal sign, you would add `(\d+)`. The parens add a capture group, `\d` matches any digit and `+` means match as many as you can.  `r":- aluhe3jm/609a4a6ff32f19a0e301085edda91d8c\?ts=(\d+)"`

Comment: `aluhe3jm/609a4a6ff32f19a0e301085edda91d8c?ts=1587097870` I want to capture this whole string.

Comment: @JovMan - The first example will let you know if the exact string is in the text. You don't really have to capture it because you already know what it is. But if you wanted to, you could put the whole thing in parens `(  )` ---- what we used to call cowboy legs but seems like nobody gets it any more ---

Comment: Sorry if you are not getting the point or I am not that verse with this community! But the string - `(aluhe3jm/609a4a6ff32f19a0e301085edda91d8c?ts=1587097870)` is a variable string. It is a portion of an URL - `(https://windscribe.com/signup/confirmemail/aluhe3jm/609a4a6ff32f19a0e301085edda91d8c?ts=1587097870)`. Till the `confirmemail/` it is constant

Comment: @JovMan - using a regex against a url can be risky because there may be escapes like %20, reordering of query strings, etc. But with that caveat, this one looks pretty save. You could use [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) but I'll just dig in with the regex. `\w` matches alphanumerics plus the underscore. `r"https://windscribe.com/signup/confirmemail/(\w+)/(\w+)\?ts=(\d+)"` would give you 3 capture groups of the variable parts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need an email id from the HTML to your result JSON object.
Try [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#module-html.parser) parser which may help you to get data based on the HTML tags.

Here is an example code for the same

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    print("Encountered a start tag:", tag)

def handle_endtag(self, tag):
    print("Encountered an end tag:", tag)

def handle_data(self, data):
    print("Encountered some data:", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
            '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
```

And the output will be

```
Encountered a start tag: html
Encountered a start tag: head
Encountered a start tag: title
Encountered some data: Test
Encountered an end tag: title
Encountered an end tag: head
Encountered a start tag: body
Encountered a start tag: h1
Encountered some data: Parse me!
Encountered an end tag: h1
Encountered an end tag: body
Encountered an end tag: html
```

Hope this will help you. Happy learning.

Comment: It's okay but it's a whole page of HTML containing 700+ lines. I think regex is better. Thanks for the quick reply though!

Comment: OP's problem is that the information is embedded in a script. An html parser can help you find the `<script>` tag but you need something else to find the data in the script. Since a regex is needed anyway, just using it from the beginning seems like the better solution to me.